# Is there a good web automator/tester for flash?

Tags: flash, web-testing, webautomation

I've been looking around for a good web automator (something that can simulate a real web user's experience) for Flash, but none seem to exist. Does anyone know of a good web automator or tester for Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Flash Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/)?

Comment: I gave it a try, but unfortunately it doesn't allow access to objects unless the site give it to you. Thanks though, it's the closest I could hope for!